# DISCORD PY The command for deleting author messages isn't executing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want it so that it autodeletes the author's message (*answer84) after it is typed, here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.content.startswith('*answer84'):
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

For some reason it just doesn't delete the message,(there is no traceback error message) any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to use the [`event` decorator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.event) instead of the `command` decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are just a few errors with your code:

### Event

You need to use the `event` decorator rather than a `command()` decorator. This is "A decorator that registers an event to listen to.". Read more about event references [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=even#discord-api-events).

### Deleting Message

Since the `on_message` event only takes in `message` as a parameter, there is no such thing as `ctx`. Remove the `ctx`, and it works!

### Code

```
@client.event #changed decorator to event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('*answer84'):
        await message.delete() #removed ctx

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

#### Edit

Moved `client.process_commands` to the bottom of the event, good practice to do so.

Comment: I think it's better to call `process_commands()` after the `if` condition.